# center align DIV by default and left align

Tags: css, html

I have DIV tags float left and right. By default the right DIV is hidden. I would like to show the first DIV in center by default when right DIV is hidden and move to left when right DIV is visible. Could you please suggest?

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left1" style="width: 50%; float: left">
        <a href id="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div id="right1" style="width: 50%; float: right; display:none"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: At what condition is the right div visible ?

Comment: Is javascript an option?

Comment: I am using Javascript function on click of the Hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange your html like so:

```
    <div id="main">
        <div id="right1" >
        </div>
        <div id="left1">
          <a href id="link">link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Set CSS like so:

```
#main {
    text-align: center;
}

#left1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left; /* if you need it left */
}

#right1 {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```

### [See example fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/GwepV/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a javascript example using actual floats http://jsfiddle.net/tprats108/DNve9/

HTML

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="left1" class="element center">
    <a href="#" id="show">Show</a>
  </div>
  <div id="right1" class="element hidden">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.element {
  width: 50%;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JS (using jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#show").click(function() {
    $("#left1").toggleClass("left center");
    $("#right1").toggleClass("right hidden");
  });
});
```